# Dash app is over-riding the CSS design of html template

Tags: python, html

I have created the ML model and want to render out in a html template which is pre-designed.

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from prepare_data import prepare_data
from oc_prepare_data import open_prepare_data
from transform_data import transform_data
from transform_data import open_transform_data
from timesteps_split import split_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from date_check import get_date
from datetime import date

# Load the model
model = load_model(r'D:/PyCharm/Prediction_Deployment/models/predict.h5')

# Initialize Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__, title='OHLC Predictions')

# Serve static files from the template folder
server = app.server
server.static_folder = 'templates/assets'

# Declare variables
n_per_in = 30
n_steps_out = 1

# Prepare data
df = prepare_data()

data, scaler = transform_data(df)

data = data.tail(30)

x = split_sequences(data.values, n_per_in, n_steps_out)

# Make predictions
pred = model.predict(x)

inv_predict = open_scaler.inverse_transform(pred)

prediction = df['PrvValue'].tail(1) * inv_predict[0]

# Format date
date_object = df.index[len(df) - 1]
formatted_date = date_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
pred_date = get_date(formatted_date)
today = date.today()

# Read index.html
with open('templates/index.html', 'r') as file:
    index_html = file.read()

# Render predicted values in the HTML
index_html = index_html.replace('{{pred_date}}', str(pred_date))
index_html = index_html.replace('{{Prediction}}', str(prediction))

#Set the layout to be the HTML content
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Markdown(index_html)
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Issue is the html template is not being properly rendered even though it shows the predicted value. It is rendering looks similar to when we open a source code of a webpage. How to slove this issue as I do not want use the default Dash rendering. And have plan to render more output in various sections of the template.